# Powershell: Issues converting curl GET response to array

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, convertfrom-json

I'm unable to convert a GET response received with curl in Powershell to an array using ConvertFrom-Json. The request is pulling a list of users from a webapp. A couple JSON validators say the JSON is valid (FWIW). The results look like the data being converted from JSON is being crammed into one element in an array.

**Sample JSON:**

```
{"adRecordsSize":0,"azureRecordSize":0,"manualRecordsSize":76,"records":[{"id":"0-0","key":"someone","position":0,"sourceType":"Manual"},{"id":"0-1","key":"someone1","position":1,"sourceType":"Manual"},{"id":"0-2","key":"someone2","position":2,"sourceType":"Manual"},{"id":"0-3","key":"someone3","position":3,"sourceType":"Manual"}],"tisRecordsSize":0}
```

The results I'm looking for are an array I can work with, something like this (really all I need is the usernames):

```
id  key  position  sourceType
0-0  someone  0  Manual
0-1  someone1  1  Manual
0-2  someone2  2  Manual
0-3  someone3  3  Manual
```

Here's the first code I tried, which at least produces something:

```
$request = @()
$request= curl.exe -H "Csrf-Token:nocheck" -H $token -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" $uri | ConvertFrom-Json
$request
```

Results below look like everything is crammed into one element or property (forgive my lack of terminology), but I was expecting an array containing an element for each item in the table I'm pulling from. Or is this multiple elements that ConvertFrom-Json isn't splitting up as it should?:

```
adRecordsSize     : 0
azureRecordSize   : 0
manualRecordsSize : 3
records           : {@{id=0-0; key=someone; position=0; sourceType=Manual}, @{id=0-1; key=someone1; position=1; sourceType=Manual}, @{id=0-2; key=someone2; position=2; sourceType=Manual}, @{id=0-3; key=someone3; position=3; 
                    sourceType=Manual}...}
tisRecordsSize    : 0
```

So instead I try:

```
$request = curl.exe -H "Csrf-Token:nocheck" -H $token -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" $uri | Select-Object -Property records | ConvertFrom-Json
```

That results in an empty array. I change the select-object command to "Select-Object -Property *" in the pipeline: Same empty array.

So now I try this:

```
$request = curl.exe -H "Csrf-Token:nocheck" -H $token -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" $uri
$data = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $request 
$data
```

The results are the same as the first step I tried!

So now this:

```
$request = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$request = curl.exe --request GET -H "Csrf-Token:nocheck" -H $token -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" $uri | Select-Object -Property * | ConvertFrom-Json
$request
```

Results in:
`"ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: ."`

I've tried a few other permutations, including using Out-String before ConvertFrom-Json, but with no success. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this??

Comment: "Results below look like everything is crammed into one element or property" <-- that's just PowerShell's default formatting. Try interacting with the resulting element, eg. `$request.records`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is simply PowerShell trying to be helpful by showing a compact string representation of the more complex objects acturally stored in the `records` property.

If you let it display the `records` value alone, you'll see exactly what you're looking for:

```
PS ~> $request.records

id  key      position sourceType
--  ---      -------- ----------
0-0 someone         0 Manual
0-1 someone1        1 Manual
0-2 someone2        2 Manual
0-3 someone3        3 Manual


PS ~> $request.records |Format-List


id         : 0-0
key        : someone
position   : 0
sourceType : Manual

id         : 0-1
key        : someone1
position   : 1
sourceType : Manual

id         : 0-2
key        : someone2
position   : 2
sourceType : Manual

id         : 0-3
key        : someone3
position   : 3
sourceType : Manual
```